# How can i use foreach on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I am trying to do a trigger but i have got a issue.All i want to do is if i have a order and when order is done, I will change the isprogress to false from my orders table. Then tirgger will be active and change the values of the unitsinstock and unitsinorder from my product table.
But i got issue on foreach.
There is my database code

```
CREATE TABLE Products(
ProductId serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
ProductName character varying(15) NOT NULL,
SupplierId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CategoryId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
UnitPrice numeric  NOT NULL,
UnitsInStock SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
UnitsOnOrder SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
Discount NUMERIC DEFAULT 0);

Create TABLE Orders(
OrderId serial PRIMARY key not null,
CustomerId text NOT NULL,
ShipperId smallint NOT NULL,
OrderDate date,
RequiredDate date,
Total DECIMAL not null,
IsProgress BOOLEAN DEFAULT True,
IsDiscount BOOLEAN DEFAULT False);


CREATE TABLE OrderDetails(
OrderId smallint NOT NULL ,
ProductId SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
Quantity SMALLINT NOT NULL);
```

and my function

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION reduce_quantity() RETURNS TRIGGER as $$
declare _orderid SMALLINT;
DECLARE _productid SMALLINT;
DECLARE _quantity SMALLINT;
BEGIN
_orderid := (select orderid from "orders" where isprogress = false);
foreach _productid,_quantity in (select productid,quantity from orderdetails where 
orderid =_orderid)
loop
update "products" set "unitsinstock" ,"unitsonorder" = "unitsinstock"- 
_quantity,"unitsonorder"= - "unitsonorder"-_quantity where orderdetails.productid = 
_productid;
end loop;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I think, you ned not loop, It can be done by simple query

Comment: Unrelated, but: `DECLARE` starts a _block_ where you can define multiple variables. There is no need to start a new block for each variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a loop or storing the intermediate results in variables.

You have access to all columns of the changed row in the `new` record of a trigger, so there is no need to retrieve that from the `orders` table.

You can change multiple rows with a single UPDATE, to bring in the information from the `orderdetails` table you can use a FROM clause:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION reduce_quantity() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
as $$
begin
   update products pr
       set unitsinstock = unitsinstock - od.quantity,
           unitsinorder = unitsinorder - od.quantity
   from orderdetails od
   where od.productid = pr.productid
     and od.orderid = new.orderid;

   return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

The trigger can be created in a way that it only fires when the `isprogress` flag is changed from true to false:

```
create trigger orders_trigger
   after update on orders 
   for each row
   when (new.isprogress = false and old.isprogress = true)
   execute procedure reduce_quantity();
```